# Django channels, se puede atender los mensajes de un usuario haciendo uso de un proceso individual por usuario?

Tags: django

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto el Djnago en el que un usuario controla una simulación muy simple paso por paso utilizando un botón, estoy usando channels para la comunicación con el servidor.

Me gustaría que se pudiera realizar un proceso individual por cada usuario (tomando en cuenta la ip para identificarse por ejemplo), esto con el fin de poder mantener disponible los datos de la simulación (esto debido a que es bastante información).

Lo que he podido averiguar es que haciendo uso de

```
python manage.py runworker
```

se ejecutan procesos que atienden las peticiones, pero estas no realizan ninguna distinción y procesan los mensajes como vienen llegando.

Se podría por ejemplo, configurar estos procesos para que cada uno atienda a un usuario a la ves y que no acepte a ningún otro hasta que se le indique?

O tendrán alguna sugerencia de como podría hacer algo similar?

La idea principal es que cada usuario que use mi aplicación sea atendido por un proceso el cual se mantenga recibiendo las peticiones se ese único usuario, como si fueran secciones.